# Regex for template style variable for an article snippet

Tags: php, regex

I'm making a blog management system of the sort. I allow the user to define templates for each page, like the blog home page, category pages, and the blog entry pages.

For the home page and category listings, I would like the user to have a template variable in the style of `{#BLOG:PREVIEW:120#}` where it would then show the first 120 characters of the entry.

What I've tried:

```
 $content = preg_replace("/{#BLOG:PREVIEW:(.*?)#}/", substr($entry, 0, $1), $template);
```

But I get:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_LNUMBER, expecting T_VARIABLE or '$'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use a [regular expression callback](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) for what you want to do:

```
$content = preg_replace_callback("/{#BLOG:PREVIEW:(.*?)#}/", function($arr) uses($entry) {
    return substr($entry, 0, $arr[1]);
}, $template);
```

If you don't have a version of PHP that supports anonymous functions:

```
function template_replace($arr) {
    // This global variable could be replaced with an object member, if inside a class
    global $entry;
    return substr($entry, 0, $arr[1]);
}

$content = preg_replace_callback("/{#BLOG:PREVIEW:(.*?)#}/", 'template_replace', $template);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that:

```
echo preg_replace_callback('~\{#BLOG:PREVIEW:\K\d++~',
    function($nb) use ($entry) {
        return substr($entry, 0, $nb[0]);
    }, $template);
```

Comment: This doesn't work, as you'll notice the regular expression is using the `$template` variable, while `substr()` is using the `$entry` variable.